# Old wall - need help

Tags: walls, paint, plaster

I have this old wall - over 200 years old. I began to remove old paint. There were about 4 to 5 layers of paint there. The problem is, I can't get the last layer of. It seems to be oil based and the wall surface is rough. This means - sanding wont help, simply scraping doesn't cut it and using a heatgun has almost no effect at all. Here's a picture of the wall.
[image]

This green bit is what I'm talking about. My question is - can I simply replaster it. Will it stay solid? Since the surface is rough, it should stick...right?

Comment: You probably already considered this, but just in case - old paint like that might be lead-based, so exercise caution when scraping and sanding.

Comment: It might be...I'm actually 80 % sure about it. BUT...how can I be 100 % sure, is there any special way to test this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. First make sure you have a rough surface. Then apply several coats of stain killer. Make sure it's alcohol base. This means it has shellac in it which is an excellent sealer. I prefer zinzer it's not as sloppy as kilz. Then get some easysand drywall patch, mix it up and apply with wide knife. This is one way. I'm sure you will hear more.